# Python data[i] to data[i+100] < # (eg. 50)

Tags: python, list, inequality

I have a list containing a large amount of data. If I want to set a if statement as the pseudo code below:

```
if data[i] to data[i+100] < 50:
    data[i] == 1
```

Is there any way that I don't need to type something like below?

```
data[i] <50 and data[i+1] <50 and data[i+2] <50 and .... and data[i+100] <50:
```

Because it'd just be too time consuming. If anyone knows the faster way, pls let me know. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
if all(data[i+k] < 50 for k in range(0,101)):
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `all(..)` for that over a *slicing* of the list:

```
if all(x < 50 for x in data[i:i+101]):
    data[i] = 1 # probably you want assignment?
```

You have to write `i:i+101` as slicing (and not `i:i+100`), since the upper bound is *exclusive*.

Or you can use `range(..)` and save on making a slice-copy of the list:

```
if all(data[j] < 50 for j in range(i,i+101)):
    data[i] = 1 # probably you want assignment?
```

Note that although you do not type all these conditions separately, of course Python will still perform iteration (and evaluate *at most* 101 such expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) over the values, checking your requirement, and then can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to ensure that they meet it:

```
>>> data = range(1000)
>>> all(map(lambda i: i < 50, data[:100]))
# => True
```

To break down whats going on:

- `data[:101]` gets a slice of the first 101 items in the array
- `map` iterates over those items and returns a boolean if passed our check `i < 50`. ie. the resulting list is `[True, True, True, ...]`
- `all` then checks that every value is True

Then you can replace the items with some smart slicing:

```
if all(map(lambda i: i < 50, data[:100])):
     data = [1] * 100 + data[100:]
```